# Replacing toaster oven with convection oven or convection microwave?

Tags: oven, microwave, convection

I am getting new counter tops and want to move the toaster oven off the counter.

Would an oven with a convection function be an equivalent replacement for the toaster convection oven?

Alternately, would a convection microwave be a good replacement for the toaster oven?

Do these devices serve similar purposes?

Comment: "Better" is subjective and not something we can answer here. I've edited your question to something that we can answer: whether they serve the same purpose. If I have missed your point, please feel free to [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: This depends on what you use the toaster oven for? Reheating food? Toasting bread? Cooking?

Answer (score 2):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if I've read your question correctly, you already have a toaster oven with a convection function and are considering options for replacing it. If that's the case, you know how convection cooking fits into your lifestyle, and when and why you like to use it.

Hopefully I can help with one part of your question! We recently bought a new regular oven and a new toaster oven, both with convection options. The convection functions work exactly the same way and serve the same purpose, which is primarily to cook food more quickly and evenly. My oven takes longer to pre-heat, which makes sense because it's bigger, but that's the only major difference. The actual cooking time doesn't vary, even though I originally thought it would. I use each appliance at different times depending on various factors, but I cook the same foods in both, and the end result is very much the same.

I don't have any experience with convection microwaves, so I'm sorry but I can't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends on what equipment you already have, and if you are willing to replace your (current?) microwave or oven.  Also, do you have room for the convection microwave?  It would have to be above your range, if you don't want it on the countertop anymore.

Another factor would be what kinds of food you would cook - convection ovens are typically much larger and can hold more space, have several racks, etc.  Hope that gives you a few things to consider.